# url modification with django template tags

Tags: django, templates, django-templates

`aaa.com/clients/view/DB38326B-65EC-4CB2-9860-E8F120109B9D/help/`

I am trying to get rid of the `guid` part `AB38326B-65EC-4CB2-9860-E8F120109B9D`
and trying to forward url to `aaa.com/clients/view/help/`.

How can I do this in Django template tags? Is it possible with built-in ones?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could just redirect on your view while passing the queryset for the GUID to it.

```
 return HttpResponseRedirect("/path/")
```

Or do the redirect in your URL's

```
from django.views.generic.simple import redirect_to

urlpatterns = patterns('',   
    (r'^one/$', redirect_to, {'url': '/another/'}),

    #etc...
)
```